# Blender 2.93 start error 87

Tags: installation

Downloaded and installed Blender 2.93. Rebooted and tried to start Blender but was given the message, "LoadLibrary failed with error 87: the parameter is incorrect. Blender launch failed. Any solutions?

Comment: Try updating your graphics drivers - I'm 90% sure this will fix it.

Comment: drivers are current and latest.

Comment: Strange... I believe you - still, everything I can find related to that error message, not only with blender, but other softwares as well (such as AutoCAD and 3DBuilder) all describe the problem being related to an incorrect driver.  https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/AutoCAD-startup-error-load-liabrary-failed-with-error-87.html - AND - https://blenderartists.org/t/startup-problem/1241284/5

Comment: I know. That was what my online search found also. I'm at a loss at this point.

Comment: Apparently the error is Windows generated, and not blender generated, if that helps narrow it down at all - Although probably not :(

Comment: 2.93 updated the version of python used by blender.  given that it's not a driver issue, I would take a look at the python install to see if something is wrong there.

Comment: I have no idea how to see if the python install was at fault. And if it was, i have no idea how to fix that other than to uninstall and then reinstall.

Comment: If reinstalling doesn't help and you can't fix the cause of the issue on Windows side, I would suggest you try the portable version (`*.zip`) https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.93/